# Clean Url for MVC index method with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and Google hasn't been much help so I will ask here.
What I'm trying to do is simple (I would had thought) I want to pass a string to the index method but it generally looks like:

http://mydomain.com/home/index/mystring

and I want:

http://mydomain.com/mystring

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 4):

You could define the following route in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyStringRoute",
    "{*mystring}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

which will invoke the `Index` action of the `Home` controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string mystring)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just what I needed! Cheers for that mate ;-)